# Unity keep adding 90º with every click

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to rotate an Image 90º with every button click. My problem is when I clicked it only turn to exactly 90º. When I click again it does not go to 180º, 270º and back to 0º on the forth click.

```
public Image image;

public void WheelClicker()
{
    image.gameObject.transform.DORotate(new Vector3(0, 0, image.gameObject.transform.rotation.z + 90), 1);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`transform.rotation` is a [`Quaternion`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.html) value! unless you know exactly what you are doing you should never touch its individual components (`x`,`y`,`z`,`w`). The value `transform.rotation.z` is **not** the value you are looking for!

You should rather use the [`transform.eulerAngles`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-eulerAngles.html)

```
public Image image;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) WheelClicker();
}

public void WheelClicker()
{
    // always prevent concurrent animations
    if (DOTween.IsTweening(image.transform)) return;

    image.transform.DORotate(image.transform.eulerAngles + new Vector3(0, 0, 90), 1);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

From the [DOTween docs](http://dotween.demigiant.com/documentation.php) (under "Rigidbody"), it seems that you need to use either WorldSpaceAdd or LocalSpaceAdd as your rotation mode. Then, you write something like: gameObject.transform.DORotate(new Vector3(0, 0, 90), 1, RotateMode.WorldAxisAdd).

Just make sure the user can't trigger a rotation during a rotation, potentially knocking you off your 90/180/270 course. The simplest way I can think to do this is:

```
if(!DOTween.IsTweening(transform) && Input.GetKeyUp("space"))
{
    transform.DORotate(new Vector3(0, 0, 90), 1, RotateMode.WorldAxisAdd);
}
```

In the case that pressing space would trigger the tween.

Comment: Yes that was going to cause an issue thanks. Unfortunately the image still only rotates to 90 and no further on subsequent clickers.

Comment: You should base it on the `image` object's rotation: (image.transform.rotation.y + 90). Currently you're basing it on the Game Object that the script is attached to.

Comment: Thanks, careless typing when asking the question. I have corrected the code. The same issue stands though.

Comment: Even rotating just normal gameobject I'm getting the same problem. Looking into it now

Comment: Yeah trying without DoTween I got the same

Comment: I think I figured it out, see edit. If there are any DOTween experts out there, please do tell what the simplest way to ensure one tween at a time is.

Answer (score 1):

this two work for me:

```
GameObject go;
float someValue = 0;
void Update()
{
        someValue += 1;
        go.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(someValue, 0, 0);
}
```

and this one:

```
GameObject go;
void Update()
{
    go.transform.Rotate(0, 90, 0, Space.World);
}
```

so try maybe something like this in your code:

```
public Image image;
int someValue = 0;
public void WheelClicker()
{
someValue += 90;
image.gameObject.transform.eulerAngles(new Vector3(0, 0,someValue ), 1);
}
```

or:

```
public Image image;
public void WheelClicker()
{
image.gameObject.transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, 0, 90), 1);
}
```

Comment: this is great thanks but I need to include DoTween for the animation when rotating